# Include file in array

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have this code

```
$__routes = array(

"Home"                    => "index.php",
"Contact"                 => "contact.php",
"Register"                => "register.php",

);
```

and i have example.php file like this

```
"Support"                 => "support.php",
"Success"                 => "success.php",
"Act"                     => "activate.php",
```

I want to include example.php file in "$__routes array"

Something to be like

```
$__routes = array(

"Home"                    => "index.php",
"Contact"                 => "contact.php",
"Register"                => "register.php",

include 'example.php';

);
```

Please how i can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without changing example.php. Each file must be valid PHP code on its own, because the include only happens at runtime (i.e. when this exact line of code is reached), not at parse time (i.e. when the file is loaded)

One way to accomplish what you need would be

**example.php**

```
return array(
    "Support"                 => "support.php",
    "Success"                 => "success.php",
    "Act"                     => "activate.php"
);
```

**main file**

```
$__routes = array(
    "Home"                    => "index.php",
    "Contact"                 => "contact.php",
    "Register"                => "register.php"
) + (include 'example.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your intention correctly, You could include one file into  the other one and merge the arrays:

```
$merged_aray = array_merge($__routes, $array2);
```

Where `$array2` equals:

```
"Support"                 => "support.php",
"Success"                 => "success.php",
"Act"                     => "activate.php"
```